# Does VisualStudio 2017 already support C++17 code contracts?

Tags: c++, assert, c++17, contract

does anyone know whether VS2017 already has support for code contracts as seen here [C++17 code contracts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31317155/what-are-contracts-in-c17)?

When I try to use them using

```
explicit IniHandler(std::string fileName) [[expects: fileName != nullptr]]
{
    this->fileName = fileName;
}
```

It does not seem to work.

I am using the command line option `/std:c++latest` but still I get the warning
"Identifier excpected".

Any help is gladly appreciated :)

Comment: I don't think it's part of C++17

Comment: Contracts aren't even scheduled for C++17, and even if they were, Visual Studio 2017 doesn't have a complete implementation of all C++17 features.

Comment: @CodyGray alright, thats the (sad) answer. Thank you and Guillaume Racicot as well.

Comment: MSVS 2017 feature list: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/10/c17-features-in-vs-2017-3/

Comment: @NathanOliver thank you, this is great.

Comment: Comparison `fileName != nullptr` is wrong anyway. Did you imply that `fileName` is actually a `char const *`? You could've used `_In_z_` SAL annotation in this case.

Comment: I should go for `!fileName.empty()` right? @Vtt

Comment: Yes, and you could also pass `std::string const & fileName` to avoid unnecessary creation of temporary string object.

Comment: @VTT thank you, I did not know that

Comment: In this case, @VTT, since the function needs a local copy of the `fileName` object, it actually makes more sense to pass it by value. It can then be moved into the field, rather than copied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contracts are not part of C++17, and AFAIK there isn't even a TS (technical specification) available. The latest paper on contracts is [P0542R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0542r0.html).

Regardless, you can find [all available C++17 features here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/10/c17-features-in-vs-2017-3/) as [NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver) mentioned in the comments.